# How to output two vectors that are iteratively filled using foreach?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I am trying to translate a for loop to a loop using `foreach`.

I have tried several output methods playing with the `.combine` argument, but I cannot output the two vectors that I create by first initilizing them to hold 1e4 zeros and then refilling each entry at each iteration.

In particular, I cannot recover the vectors that are created in this way:

```
Va = numeric(1e4)
Vb = numeric(1e4)

result = foreach(j = 1:1e4, .multicombine=TRUE) %dopar%
{

    ... rest of the code ...

    Va[j] = sample(4,1)
    Vb[j] = sample(5,1)
    list(retSLSP, retBH)
}
```

Note that j is the loop variable in the `foreach` loop. Note also that the computations I showed are not the actual computations I have in my code, but are equivalent for the purposes of the example.

Comment: This is not how foreach loops work. They follow the functional programming paradigm insofar as they don't allow side effects. They are actually more similar to sapply than to for loops. In summary, you can't fill a vector with a foreach loop (well, there is a way, but it's bad practice and inferior to a for loop).

Comment: Thanks, I suspected it wasn't just difficult but perhaps (close to) impossible to do. The computation speed I gained from using a foreach loop instead of a for loop was noticeable but not critical. But still, maybe I can avoid this approach of filling vectors. Is there a way to let the foreach function know that I want those two values saved at each iteration (without creating the Va and Vb vectors at all)?

Comment: You can return c(a,b) and use .combine = rbind to get a matrix.  Then just index the two columns to retrieve two vectors.

Comment: Thanks thc! It works perfectly. I'm new to functional programming so thanks for answering what probably is a very basic question.

Comment: @AlbertDorador An easy solution would be to use shared memory. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shared-memory to be accessed by all threads.

```
library(bigmemory)
V <- big.matrix(1e4, 2)
desc <- describe(V)

result = foreach(j = 1:1e4, .multicombine=TRUE) %dopar%
{
    V <- bigmemory::attach.big.matrix(desc)

    ... rest of the code ...

    V[j, 1] = sample(4,1)
    V[j, 2] = sample(5,1)
    list(retSLSP, retBH)
}

Va <- V[, 1]
Vb <- V[, 2]
rm(V, desc)
```

Although, it would be better to parallelize by blocks than to do it for the whole loop.
An example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45196081/6103040

Comment: @AlbertDorador If you're okay with the answer, you can accept it.